# How to use db4o IObjectContainer in a web application ? (Container lifetime ?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, db4o

I am evaluating db4o for persistence for a ASP .NET MVC project.

I am wondering how I should use the IObjectContainer in a web context with regards to object lifetime. As I see it, I can do one of the following:

1. Create the IObjectContainer at application startup and keep the same instance for the entire application lifetime.
2. Create one IObjectContainer per request.
3. Start a server, and get a client IObjectContainer for each database interaction.

What are the implications of these options, in terms of performance and concurrency ?

Since the database is locked when an IObjectContainer is opened, I am pretty sure that option 2) would get me some problems with concurrency - would this also be the case for option 1 ?

As I understand it, if I retrieve an object from an IObjectContainer, it must be saved by the same IObjectContainer instance - in order for db4o to identify it as being the same object. Therefore, If I choose option 3), I would have to retrieve the original object, make the necessary changes (copy data from a modified object), and then store it using the same IObjectContainer. Is this true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1) can get you into serious trouble because you will effectively share a transaction amongst all requests. I don't think that this is a feasible option.

As you already identified, option 3) is fraught with its own perils because you will have to keep track of object identity manually - a tedious and extremely error-prone task. This really destroys all the beauty of the object database. Also, from what I know the overhead of creating `IObjectContainer` is not small so this will be far too expensive.

This pretty much leaves us with option 2, which does not lock the database when opened in client-server mode as far as I know - where did you find that informaiton? So the best idea is to open an `IObjectServer` on application startup and open new a `IObjectContainer` per-request, or connect to a remote server using TCP per-request.